# Synchronize two listviews on top of each other in a FrameLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Here is my current layout configuration:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The top listview is basically a scrolling overlay for the base listview: list_1, they must have the same height. The overlay is not visible on idle but when dragging it has some alpha, and displays list_1 current section.

I made it so that we have list 1 and list 2 have the same content height, but they have DIFFERENT LAYOUT for their own list item.

Knowing that list_2 here will catch touch events here, I want to sync both listview scroll offset. I have partly managed it with this example:

```
mListView2.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    View c = mListViewMonths.getChildAt(0);
                    int scrolly = -c.getTop() + mListViewMonths.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
                    mListViewWeeks.setScrollY(scrolly);
                }
            });
```

At the exception that listview1 gets scrolled, but when going down no list items of listview1 are drawn. What am I missing here?

Or perhaps better, dispatch the touch event to both listview, instead of all those scrolling techniques. Thoughts?

Comment: I have a possible solution that I use to have two listViews within the save view.  The solution includes using a scrollview. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I would probably look for another solution. That sounds hackish at best. For example, you could use a framelayout as your item, with your different layouts in it.

Comment: Hmm looking at the comments I received I should probably head in another direction, my guess would be to use one listview only, too hackish that's true. But the effect I want to realize requires quite some work. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to realize this by using this helper class here:

[Helper class for calculating relative scroll offsets in a ListView](https://gist.github.com/cogentapps/6680353)

Then in list2 scroll listener simply do:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int incrementalOffset = mScrollTracker.calculateIncrementalOffset(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
    mListView2.scrollListBy(-incrementalOffset);
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

This is bit of a hack but should work.

**activity_main_activity_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.recyclerview.MainActivityList">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:scrollbars="none"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:scrollbars="none"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivityList**

```
public class MainActivityList extends Activity {

    ScrollView scroll1, scroll2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_list);

        ListView list_1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_1);
        // Set list_1 Adapter
        SetListOneHeight.setListViewHeight(list_1);

        ListView list_2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_2);
        // Set list_2 Adapter
        SetListTwoHeight.setListViewHeight(list_2);

        scroll1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll1);
        scroll2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll2);

        scroll1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = scroll1.getScrollY();
                scroll2.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Create Two Seperate Java Classes**

**SetListOneHeight**

```
public class SetListOneHeight {
    public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

**SetListTwoHeight**

```
public class SetListTwoHeight {
    public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seeing the Linearlayout, are you talking here about two successive listview vertically, or two listview on top of each other?

Comment: @Tíbó They would be vertically within a LinearLayout. list_1 on top of list_2. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: oh sorry! On top of each other, I mean on a z-basis. One listview at z=0 and another one at z=1. Apologies for not formulating my question right!

Comment: @Tíbó No worries.  I had already had this code in my library.  You are trying to scroll the second listView based on the first listview?

Comment: @Tíbó I have never seen that before, are the listViews the same height?

Comment: the top listview is basically a scrolling overlay for the base listview: list_1, they must have the same height. The overlay is not visible on idle but when dragging it has some alpha, and displays list_1 current section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80327/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-tibo).